# Show only the notifications of the user self Laravel

Tags: html, database, laravel, filter, user-management

I have made a website where you can make a report, you have to submit a form with your account, and then a admin can handle that report, so the user can log in and see the reports and the status of it, but I want that the user can only see his own reports and not others?
Here is my html

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mTop">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @if(session('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{session('message')}}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Retourmeldingen</div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Firmanaam</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Verwerkingstijd</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                @foreach($retours as $retour)
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">{{ $retour->firmaname }}</th>
                                        <td><a href="{{ route('return.show', $retour->id) }}">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-0">Bekijk
                                                </button>
                                            </a></td>
                                        <td>@if( $retour->status === 0)
                                                <a href="{{ route('return.edit', $retour->id) }}">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-0">Wijzig
                                                    </button>
                                                </a>
                                            @else
                                                <a href="{{ route('return.edit', $retour->id) }}">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-0" disabled>
                                                        Wijzig
                                                    </button>
                                                </a>
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>@if( $retour->status === 0)
                                                Open
                                            @else
                                                <i style="color: #05af00; font-size: 25px"
                                                   class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                                            @endif</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if($retour->status === 0)
                                                Nog niet verwerkt
                                            @elseif($retour->diffInDays === 0)
                                                Zelfde dag verwerkt
                                            @elseif( $retour->diffInDays === 1)
                                                {{ $retour->diffInDays }} dag
                                            @elseif( $retour->diffInDays >= 1)
                                                {{ $retour->diffInDays }} dagen
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <form method="post"
                                                  action="{{ route('return.destroy', $retour->id) }}">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('DELETE')
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-0"><i
                                                        class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                @endforeach
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-3">{{ $retours->links() }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

So what I want is that the user can see only his own reports based on the firmaname, what I have now is that you can see all the reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion you should apply filters at controller level, returning to view only collection of reports owns by the consultant user.

That should be accomplished by `user_id` field in reports table in case that any report belongs to a unique user, or a pivot table in case that a report can have many owners.

So, if a report only belongs to a unique user, you should filter in your sql query by a WHERE statement such as:

```
$reports = Reports::where('user_id', $auth->user()->id)->where('other conditions')->get();
```

And then, in your view yo will have only reports that belongs to current user, which also solves a security issue.